# Why is Assuming[...] ignoring the assumption?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

Let's say I want to compute a quantity like $e^{i \pi \vert \vec a \vert}$, and for a certain vector `a = {a1,a2,a3}` I assume it has length 1, so the quatity would be -1. My minimal example in Mathematica looks like

```
a = {a1, a2, a3};
Assuming[{a1^2 + a2^2 + a3^2 == 1}, 
ComplexExpand[Exp[I * Pi * Norm[a]]]]
```

which evaluates to $\cos(\sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2} \pi) + i \sin(\sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2} \pi)$ instead of $1$. What am I doing wrong so that `Assuming[...]` does not work as intentioned?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Assuming` works by adding conditions to `$Assumptions`. Some functions make use of `$Assumptions` and some do not. Generally, it is explicitly mentioned in the documentation, if the function does apply `$Assumptions`; such functions usually have an `Assumptions` option. Sometimes functions with the `Assumptions` options results in a more careful use of the conditions in the option setting than when setting `$Assumptions` to them (for example, `Integrate`).

That said, `ComplexExpand` does not make use of `$Assumptions`. Neither does ordinary evaluation of expressions. A common way to apply `$Assumptions` to an expression is to use `Simplify`.

```
aa = {a1, a2, a3};
Assuming[{a1^2 + a2^2 + a3^2 == 1}, 
 Simplify@ComplexExpand[Exp[I*Pi*Norm[aa]]]]

(* -1 *)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
a = {a1, a2, a3};

Assuming[{a1^2 + a2^2 + a3^2 == 1}, 
 ComplexExpand[Exp[I*Pi*Norm[a]]] // FullSimplify]

FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[Exp[I*Pi*Norm[a]]], 
 Assumptions -> {a1^2 + a2^2 + a3^2 == 1}]
```

---

```
-1
-1
```

Comment: You don't need `Assumptions -> `. The second argument of FullSimplify are the assumptions.